# error: (-215:Assertion failed) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0 in function 'calc'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

[I'm trying out this git](https://github.com/prouast/heartbeat) and  I get this error below

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.1) ../modules/video/src/lkpyramid.cpp:1257: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (npoints = prevPtsMat.checkVector(2, CV_32F, true)) >= 0 in function 'calc'
```

Hardware:

Raspberry pi 3B v1.2

RAM:1GB

Swapfile:4GB

Software:

Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) aarch64

Pip packages: opencv-python-headless and opencv-contrib_python == 4.7.0.72

the video I'm trying to pass in is 480x600, 30fps, about 30sec long.